# OracleSolaris 11.2 -- simple file I/O, cc warning

Tags: file-io, solaris, opensolaris

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  fd = open("abc.txt", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0)
  {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("fd %d\n", fd);
  close(fd);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}
```

Now I build it:

```
$ cc -errwarn=%all -o ~/tmp/aa ~/tmp/a.c
warning: bad message tag: /export/home/rmashak/tmp/a.call
$ cc -V
cc: Sun C 5.12 SunOS_i386 2011/11/16
```

It does execute fine, but what's the warning all about?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I updated my question with compiler information.

Comment: From the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21990/bjapr.html#bjaqj) I'd venture that it's a compiler bug.  Can you update the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I have insufficient reputation to add a comment...  This does look like a compiler bug with the parser. Compiling with later version of cc does not produce this error.

```
$ cc -V                                 
cc: Sun C 5.13 SunOS_i386 2014/10/20
$ cc -errwarn=%all -o ~/tmp/aa ~/tmp/a.c
$
```

In your output cc appears to have presented the source filename concatenated with the remainder of '-errwarn' tag 'all', odd!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have passed an unrecognized option to -errwarn:

```
% cc -errwarn=%mumblefrotz -o hello hello.c
warning: bad message tag: %mumblefrotz
```

It appears your shell somehow converted the `%` in your command into `/export/home/rmashak/tmp/a.c` before passing it to the compiler.  It looks like some shells such as zsh may expand `%` signs specially in command processing - check the docs for whichever shell you use.

If you're using recent versions of Solaris Studio, the `%` is optional to avoid problems like this - you can change your command instead to be:

```
cc -errwarn=all -o ~/tmp/aa ~/tmp/a.c
```